# If I implement suggestions from a review, where do I reply to say what I did / thank the reviewer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Suppose I get a detailed review and implement many things in response. Where do I reply to say what I did? Presumably, reviewers want to know that their suggestions were useful.

Comment: Not an answer, but an upvote, possibly accept and following there suggestions are nice, :)

Comment: The comments are useful for this.

Comment: If you want the revised code to be reviewed again, you may post a follow-up question (and link to the original post); if you just want to say "thanks", then give an upvote, a checkmark, or even a bounty. CR isn't a discussion forum, we're about the reviewing itself, not about the result of it - so the "final code" has little or no value on the site, really (is code ever "final" anyway?).

Comment: See also [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for possible options.

Comment: FWIW I saw your question in the *hot network questions* list in the side bar - that should help with getting more eyes (/votes) on the answer you got =)

Answer (score 10):

> *Presumably, reviewers want to know that their suggestions were useful.*

Indeed! As with all Stack Exchange sites, useful answers receive upvotes from readers. If you haven't done that already, give that review your upvote, and mark your question as *answered* by giving a *checkmark* to that awesome answer. If you have >50 rep and more to say than just "Thanks!" or "Awesome, +1!", you can leave a comment too, though these comments often get flagged (and soon removed) as *too chatty* or *obsolete*.

Sometimes a question doesn't get many views, and still gets awesome answers, but then these answers don't get as many views as some others (say, on some more popular question) do, and you feel like your petty +25 doesn't do justice to the awesome answer you got. **Browsing to the answerer's profile to upvote all their answers is not the solution** - *serial voting* gets automatically reversed, so voting for *users* isn't a good idea.

If you have the rep, you can award a bounty to a specific answer, specifically to reward the reviewer with additional rep from your own stash.

Code is never really *flawless* though, so you might also want to follow-up with a new question (it's rather commonly done here) - see [this Help Center page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for all the relevant information.